# website goes to a different ip address

Tags: 14.04, webserver, websites

I am maintaining a website, pcc.edu.ph , I can't seem to access it since yesterday and I tried to ping the website, it pings back but gives me a different IP not the IP provided by my DNS. I checked the A File of the dns but everything is correct, any suggestions what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I would usually suggest starting from the top:

- `whois` the domain and make sure it's pointing at your nameserver. I don't seem to be able to do this for yours. Check with your registrar.
- Check the nameserver. You've done this.
- Check your local DNS. By extension check from somebody else's. I'll make that slightly easier and do it for you.

  ```
  $ nslookup pcc.edu.ph
  Server:     127.0.0.1
  Address:    127.0.0.1#53

  ** server can't find pcc.edu.ph: SERVFAIL

  $ ping pcc.edu.ph
  ping: unknown host pcc.edu.ph
  ```

Given I couldn't get a whois response (even from their website, said it was an invalid domain) and I'm not get any resolution, I'd have to guess that the registration for the domain has lapsed in some way and is now deleted from the registry.

Comment: thanks for the answer @Oli , i would check that first thing when i return to the office, i will give an update on what will happen next, thanks again

Comment: oh just checked my subscription with my dns, and it says i don't have any domains expiring in the next 60 days, and it shows that the domain is active